# Can you create mulitple groups at once in bash?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I'm trying to create multiple groups at once and give each one an ID. Can you do this without continually using the `groupadd` command?

```
groupadd group1

groupadd group2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a set of groups with specific IDs using a for loop as follows:

```
declare -A groups
groupIds['group1']=2000
groupIds['group2']=3000
for groupName in "${!groupIds[@]}"
do
  groupadd "$groupName" --gid ${groupIds["$groupName"]}
done
```